# Mysql port forwarding with docker and proxy

Tags: mysql, docker, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am facing a problem trying to use docker and two port forwardings. Basically I have:

- A docker container hosting a MySQL database running on port 3306 in the container
- The host of the container, where port XXXX is linked to the 3306 of the container with the docker-compose command  `ports: - XXXX:3306`; I can access my container within the host using PhpMyadmin. So, so far so good
- I create a bridge with a proxy server on port 3336 created with a command: `ssh -i key.pem -R 3336:localhost:XXXX ubuntu@IP`
- I then have a client (say Mysql Workbench) which is connected to the proxy using another tunnel : `ssh -i key.pem -L 3306:3336 ubuntu@IP`

I tried to summarize everything in the following picture with XXXX being 3306 (the green box).
When I try to connect to the database using this rather complex method, it succeeds when XXXX=3306. However, when XXXX=8701 for example, it does not work anymore. Do you have any idea why ? The error I get is a classic timeout: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best,
B

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Serverfault sister site of SO provides support for server and network infrastructure related questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, which was related to the `docker-compose.yml` file;
Previously I had:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    build: 
       context: ./database
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password  --sql_mode=""
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_HOST_PORT}:${MYSQL_PORT}
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: ${MYSQL_HOST_PORT}
    env_file: ./.env
```

The trick was to have the same port in and outside of the container `${MYSQL_HOST_PORT}:${MYSQL_HOST_PORT}`

Hope it would help others in the same situation